# Document Expired

Tags: javascript, php, cross-browser

I have an index.php that has a form.

```
<form id="order" method="post" action="">
```

On the same page I have some checkboxes with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price0"  id="price0"  <?php echo $price0 ?> onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

When someone clicks on a link, and uses the back button, then firefox shows the "Document expired" error. How can I Solve this an easy way?

Is there a way to clear the $POST values when the back button is used?
Or Is there a way to redirect the back button to the index.php? but only the back button. On the Clicks I need the $POST data to filter the site content.

Comment: use POST redirect GET flow

Comment: For filtering content you should use GET in stead of POST. This way the browser also has a different entry for different content, also goes for search engines etc. If you MUST use post. Then after the post is handled redirect to a GET page with correct content like @Ghost said

Comment: GET is not an option! The Whole page is set up to use POST values and would be too complicated to change it.